# What does * mean at the beginning of a range?

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

Sorry for the noob question, but what does this asterisk mean at the beginning of a range?

```
class Matrix
  def initialize(matrix_string)
    @matrix = matrix_string.split("\n").map do |row|
        row.split.map(&:to_i)
    end
    @rows = rows.length
    @cols = columns.length
  end

  def rows
    @matrix
  end

  def columns
    @matrix.transpose
  end

  # --->>***
  def saddle_points
    [*0...@rows].product([*0...@cols]).select do |coords|
        saddle_point?(*coords)
  end
  # ***<----
end

private
  def   saddle_point?(row, col)
    (@matrix[row][col] == rows[row].max) && 
    (@matrix[row][col] == columns[col].min)
  end
end
```

Comment: that's splat operator. See http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/

Comment: Splat operator “unsplats” the `Range` as it does for `Array`: `[*0..1] #⇒ [0, 1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is stated [in the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion):

> You can turn an `Array` into an argument list with `*` (or splat) operator:
>
> ```
> arguments = [1, 2, 3]
> my_method(*arguments)
> ```

The same might be done for `Range`:

```
arguments = 1..3
my_method(*arguments) # essentially the same as my_method(1, 2, 3)
```

Also splat operator is allowed before ranges inside the array declaration to implicitly convert `Range` to `Array`:

```
[*1..3]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` unpacks an array by "splatting" its contents and converting it to an array.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the other answers, the `*` operator is used to turn an array into an argument list.

But what if the object is not an array, as in your case? Then Ruby will call `#to_a` on the object, if defined, and use the returned array instead. Otherwise, the object itself is used.

Here's the case where the object is neither an array nor does it define `#to_a`:

```
x = *4 # => [4]
```

If the object defines `#to_a`, it will be called and used, as in the case of `Range`:

```
x = *0..1 # => [0, 1]
```

To prove this, we can prepend a module to trace the call to `#to_a`:

```
module Trace
  def to_a
    puts "#to_a called"
    super
  end
end

Range.prepend(Trace)

x = *0..1
# prints "#to_a called"
# => [0, 1]
```

Note that Ruby will not call `#to_a` if your object already is of type `Array`.

We can use this on our custom types as well:

```
class Foo
  def to_a
    [1, 2, 3]
  end
end

x = *Foo.new # => [1, 2, 3]
```

By the way, Ruby's `nil` also implements `#to_a`. This allows us to pass `nil` as an argument as if nothing was passed, because `nil.to_a` returns `[]`:

```
def count(*args)
  args.count
end

count # => 0
count(*0..1) # => 2
count(*nil) # => 0
```

This can be useful when you have a variable that could be `nil` that you pass to a method which has a default value:

```
def say_hi(name = "Jane")
  puts "Hi, #{name}"
end

name = nil
say_hi(*name) # prints "Hi, Jane"
```

But if we remove `NilClass#to_a`:

```
NilClass.undef_method(:to_a)

say_hi(*name) # prints "Hi, "
```